# Dokku and persistent storage

Tags: node.js, persistent-storage, dokku

I can't figure out how to set persistent storage for my app. It is based on https://github.com/NYTimes/kyt-starter-universal. The persistent dir is supposed to be the content of /src/public/content. My storage folder is located in /home/user/content. I don't understand how deploying works. To make a production build locally, I need to run npm build && npm start. After that files are located in /build folder. From what I know, I need to make a DOCKERFILE to execute these commands after deploy (am I correct? do I need to configure ports?). But where my persistent folder needs to go? Is it

`dokku storage:mount app-name /home/user/content:/src/public/content`

or

`dokku storage:mount app-name /home/user/content:/build/content`

or just

`dokku storage:mount app-name /home/user/content:/content`
?

I see the recommended way is to use /var/lib/dokku/data/storage, but I have no access from my account, so maybe I'm missing something more.
Please forgive my ignorance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it with docker options, without using plugins.

Just add the docker options changing your folders like in this answer.
[Rails - Dokku - Paperclip: Every push to production breaks(404s) user uploaded images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626259/rails-dokku-paperclip-every-push-to-production-breaks404s-user-uploaded-i/39091104#39091104)